# Implementing a function without using if-else statements

Tags: sml

I would like to implement a function which gets as input `f g a` when `f g` are lambda functions and `a` is a parameter. The function should do as following:

```
fun foo f g a = if (g a) then (f a) else a;
> val foo = fn : ('a -> 'a) -> ('a -> bool) -> 'a -> 'a
```

Is it possible to somehow replace `if-else` with `andalso,orelse`, or some other method? I would like to implement a function without using `if-else` statements.

Edit: Looking for a way to combine two functions, one of them is `'a -> 'a` while the other one is `'a -> bool`.

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info). Could you change the question to the problem rather than the attempted solution?

Comment: @SimonShine Thanks for the reply. It actually straightforward. I implement an anonymous function `(fn x => if (g x) then (f x) else x)` and I would like somehow to remove the `if-else` statements.

Comment: Since `a` and `f a` have type *'a*, I'm not sure if there is a more elegant way to do it. (You can only replace if-then-else with andalso/orelse when the type of the branches are *bool*.) But maybe changing the names and order of the identifiers will make it more readable. I'd still like to see the context.

Answer (score 2):

if for some weird reason you don't want to use `if-else` you could pattern match to true/false. E.g. like that:

```
fun bar f g a = case (g a) of
                true => (f a)
                | false => a;

fun bari f g a = (fn true => f a | false => a)(g a);
```

But as [Simon Shine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/235908/simon-shine) already mentioned you may want to rephrase your question and describe the problem in a bigger picture if this is not what you are looking for.